# How to avoid creating new empty row when an object is pushed to array

Tags: angularjs

https://plnkr.co/edit/qUs7VH84QZGz0YlLJB70

The above link as my code when I click the save button I am getting saved and when I click cancel I am getting wrong output, and my empID is also shows only increased count value only. I tried my best to solve; I think I am not getting it.

```
$scope.getTemplate = function (employee) {
        if (employee.empID === $scope.selected.empID){
            console.log(employee.empID);
            console.log($scope.selected.empID);
            console.log("edit");
            return 'edit';
        }

        else {
            console.log("display");
            console.log(employee.empID);
            console.log($scope.selected.empID);
            return 'display';
        }
    };
```

I think I am going wrong on this function, but not able to find my error.

Comment: Please tell us what "wrong output" means. What are you expecting? What are you getting instead?

Comment: when i click save button the data i entered is pushed to employees array after pushing the object i am getting another new empty row.

Comment: another problem is when i check multiple add row button i am getting the empID value wrong its not in sequence i tried my best to solve but my bad luck

Comment: @MohanGopi: i've checked your plunk and it works fine, no additional empty rows are added. Can you please check it again?

Comment: @SmartyTwiti when i click save button its not saving even though it is saved i am getting a new empty row

Comment: @SmartyTwiti at $scope.updateEmployee = function(employee) please change empID: $scope.count,

Comment: please check my updated plunker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of updating your inserting new row.

Try like this

```
$scope.updateEmployee = function(employee) {
  var emp = $scope.employees.filter(function(x) {
    return x.empID == employee.empID
  });
  if (emp.length > 0) {
    emp[0].empID = employee.empID;
    emp[0].empName = employee.empName;
    emp[0].empEmail = employee.empEmail;
  } else {
    $scope.employees.push({
      empID: employee.empID, //.length,
      empName: employee.empName,
      empEmail: employee.empEmail
    });
  }
  //console.log($scope.employees.lenth);
  //console.log($scope.employees);
  $scope.reset();
  //console.log($scope.reset());
  $scope.getTemplate();
};
```

<kbd>**[`DEMO`](https://plnkr.co/edit/ciqM1d2X7JsLwmDu2Vpl?p=preview)**</kbd>